Server 24.04 only starts a single interface on boot
ubuntu 24.04
I had the system working as intended with just a single eth0 ethernet interface
I enabled wifi on the system, now on boot wlan0 gets a DHCP address, while eth0 just sits idle.
user@charmander:~ # ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:d9:14:dc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:d9:14:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.206/24 metric 600 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic wlan0
       valid_lft 86333sec preferred_lft 86333sec
    inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fed9:14dd/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: br-3754d51a6ecf: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:cb:0c:5d:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.30.9.1/24 brd 172.30.9.255 scope global br-3754d51a6ecf
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:cbff:fe0c:5da5/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:33:6c:18:0a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: veth90fe157@if6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-3754d51a6ecf state UP group default
    link/ether 36:bf:25:db:db:44 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::34bf:25ff:fedb:db44/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: vethe6e2821@if8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-3754d51a6ecf state UP group default
    link/ether 1a:83:61:24:ff:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::1883:61ff:fe24:ff07/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

user@charmander:~ # sudo dhclient eth0
Setting LLMNR support level "yes" for "2", but the global support level is "no".

user@charmander:~ # ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:d9:14:dc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.4/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 86397sec preferred_lft 86397sec
    inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fed9:14dc/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:d9:14:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.206/24 metric 600 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic wlan0
       valid_lft 86265sec preferred_lft 86265sec
    inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fed9:14dd/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: br-3754d51a6ecf: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:cb:0c:5d:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.30.9.1/24 brd 172.30.9.255 scope global br-3754d51a6ecf
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:cbff:fe0c:5da5/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:33:6c:18:0a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: veth90fe157@if6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-3754d51a6ecf state UP group default
    link/ether 36:bf:25:db:db:44 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::34bf:25ff:fedb:db44/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: vethe6e2821@if8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-3754d51a6ecf state UP group default
    link/ether 1a:83:61:24:ff:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::1883:61ff:fe24:ff07/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

I can manually get an DHCP address with dhcient eth0 and then everything works fine.
I have added dhclient eth0 to my /etc/rc.local so that eth0 will get an address on boot, but this is obviously less than optimal and I would prefer that both interfaces come all the way up and get DHCP leases on boot.
I do not have network manager on this system:
user@charmander:~ # sudo service NetworkManager status
Unit NetworkManager.service could not be found.0

UPDATE:
netplan:
user@charmander:/etc/netplan # ls
50-cloud-init.yaml


user@charmander:/etc/netplan # sudo cat 50-cloud-init.yaml
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    version: 2
    wifis:
        renderer: networkd
        wlan0:
            access-points:
                <SSID>:
                    password: <redacted>
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true

I have another box with ethernet only, so I just cribbed from that and added an ethernets section:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true

and now it's working as expected.  I guess the question now is, A) why did the netplan get re-written to only include the wifi interface and B) should I be confident it isn't going to get rewritten again?

Please include your netplan config in the question.

@ArturMeinild ok, that was the key, I think it's working now but now I've got to know what caused the change to the netplan conf and if I should expect it to change again?

For that, I have no clue..

All the answers are right there in the output you provided. Look again at the output you provided. Look at the filename, and re-read the comments in that file.
